# Keyboard.write writing ASCII integer value as a String

Tags: serial, keyboard, data-type

I have the following code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Keyboard.h>

SoftwareSerial ttySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Native USB only
  }

  Serial.println("Serial Initialized");

  //Set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  ttySerial.begin(115200);
  ttySerial.println("tty Initialized");

  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() 
{
  while (ttySerial.available())
    //Serial.write();
    Keyboard.write(ttySerial.read());

//    if (Serial.available())
//      ttySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

my problem is that `ttySerial.read()` is an `int` and I thought that the `Keyboard.write` method could hand integer arguments: [`Keyboard.write(32)`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.KeyboardWrite) should write "< space >" not "32".

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: i do not see `Keyboard.write(32)` in your code ... what are you doing to send byte 32 to the sketch?

Comment: @jsotola thats because I am writing byte 32 to the RX Pin using SoftwareSerial. The `ttySerial.read()` is where I recover that and want it to be written using `Keyboard.write`. Simply put `ttySerial.read()` == byte 32 (but can also take on the form of other bytes)

Comment: And what is the problem? Is this program misbehaving? If so, what it it doing? What behavior do you expect instead?

Comment: it writes 32, because you send "32". Send 32 or `' '` to simulate space bar press.

Comment: @Juraj How can I convert "32" as received from`string` to `int`? I tried using `ttySerial.read().toInt())` but I get a compilation error

Comment: @EdgarBonet The keyboard is writing the ASCII integer values instead of the ASCII character corresponding to that integer. My expectation is a `write` of the ASCII character

Comment: two separate characters are received. you can print debug messages to Serial Monitor while using HID

Comment: @Juraj should I be using `ttySerial.readString()` then? How can I read the two separate characters into a single integer value? Note sometimes the integer will be 1 digit, sometimes 2, sometimes 3

Comment: you could use parseInt. or send bytes not text. what is the sender? send ' ' not "32"

Comment: @Juraj Yes it looks like `parseInt()` is what I am looking for, thanks! Ill try it out tonight. Unfortunately the `js` serial-port library I am using only allows transmission of buffers and strings, not integers. Also, handling modifiers could become difficult by not sending the ASCII integer value. It looks like `parseInt()` will read `char`s and automatically convert the data type to `int` so that should be perfect.

Comment: why not send the characters you want to press and not the ascii codes?

Comment: @Juraj > "handling modifiers could become difficult by not sending the ASCII integer value"

Comment: You can send arbitrary data with a JavaScript buffer. For instance, both `Buffer.from([32])` and `Buffer.from(' ')` will give you a buffer holding a single byte with the numeric value 32.

Comment: @EdgarBonet for some reason that isnt working but I will mess around with it some more

Comment: @Juraj parseInt() works but is incredible slow - any alternatives? Edit: it's a little faster now idk why

Comment: it is not slow. it waits a second for the next character, because it doesn't know which is last. you could use ttySerial.setTimeout(100); (in setup)

Answer (score -1):

write will treat an int as a number and assume you want it converted to ascii.  Try casting that to char:

```
Keyboard.write((char)ttySerial.read());
```

The print class treats char variables as if they are already ascii codes.

Comment: Are you saying I should try `Keyboard.print(...)`? Or `.write` as you have?

Comment: I'm saying that either way you have to feed it a char if it is an ascii code.  And yeah, I'd probably use print there.

Comment: Well I tried `(char)...` at one point but the behavior still wasn't write but I didn't do it using `.print` not sure if that would make the difference - I'll have to try it out next week but I'll let you know

Comment: Delta_G, read the comments please